# Automatically suspend applications/services while playing games?

Tags: windows-10, performance, services, gaming

So I just built my first "gaming" system (AMD Ryzen 9 3950X with GeForce RTX 2080 Super). "Gaming" is in quotes because unfortunately this system is going to need to be multi-purpose:

- Plex server
- File server
- Minecraft server
- And various other services that I use to help Plex have content to play (including downloading, transcoding, etc).

I would like some way to pause or suspend these programs/services while I'm actually gaming. Preferably in an automatic way. Additionally it'd be nice if this tool had some brains. For instance, don't suspend the Minecraft server if I'm playing Minecraft.

Does anyone have any thoughts? It doesn't have to be a free program, I don't mind paying some money for good solution.

Comment: See @harrymc answer below.. this is a good answer.  FYI, It sounds crazy but I have made batch files that toggle the state of a bunches of services.. run the game.. and when I exit the game, it turns them back on.  Since "Game Mode".. I haven't needed to do this but it is indeed effective if Game Mode isn't giving you the performance you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 already supports a Game Mode that when enabled, Windows 10 prioritizes
processor and graphics card resources to your game. It can also stop Windows Update
from installing drivers updates or showing notifications during game-play.

Game Mode is enabled in *Settings > Gaming > Game Mode*.
Ensure also that in the Game bar section a shortcut key is assigned in
"Open the Game bar".

Windows will recognize some games automatically. The ones that is misses can be
added to the list using the Game bar.

Note that for a strong setup such a yours, in the absence of heavy
background processes you may not see a big difference in performance
when this mode is on.

Some reading:

- [2 ways to enable Game Mode in Windows 10](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/enable-game-mode-windows-10)
- [What is Game Mode in Windows 10 and what it can do for gamers](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/game-mode-windows)

Comment: I do have Game Mode enabled... and maybe that'll be enough?  I assumed it'd only stop "Windows" related things (like updates) from stealing ram/processor.  Have you heard of [Razer Cortex Game Booster](https://www.razer.com/cortex/boost)?  I just found it googling, It seems like it might do some of the stuff I want.  I don't think I can configure it per game however.

Comment: Game Mode should be enough. In any case, with your rig it's doubtful that you need it.